# Show form fields dependent on drop down box selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down box which has two values free and paid.  WHat i am trying to do is if somebody selects paid from the drop down list then more form fields are shown.

At the moment i have three issues, the first is that when the form runs it shows all the boxes, and i have to select free to hide them, what i want is the form to open with free pre-selected.

Also when i do select free only one of the boxes hide, and i want them both to hide and finally if i select free and then select paid, it does not show the first box at all.

Do i need a seperate piece of javascript for each form element or can i use one piece of javascript for all form elements that i only want to show once paid is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/kLoq3xy5/

This is my code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#listing').on('change.listing', function() {
   $("#paid").toggle($(this).val() == 'paid');
   }).trigger('change.paid');
   }); 

    <select id="listing">
      <option value="free" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">PLEASE CHOOSE</option>
      <option value="FREE">Free</option>
      <option value="PAID">Paid</option>
   </select>


  <div id="paid">
    <select name="industry" class="form-control">
      <option value="0"> -- Select Industry -- </option>
      <option value="Accounting, Banking Finance">Accounting, Banking & Finance</option>
      <option value="Administrative & Secretarial">Administrative & Secretarial</option>
    </select>
   </div>


 <div id="paid">
  <select name="industry1" class="form-control">
    <option value="0"> -- Select Industry -- </option>
    <option value="Accounting, Banking Finance">Accounting, Banking & Finance</option>
    <option value="Administrative & Secretarial">Administrative & Secretarial</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 elements with the same id in HTML. You can either put all 'paid' form elements inside one `<div id="paid">` or keep them separate and use `<div class="paid">` instead.

As to creating elements hidden initially, you can add `style="display:none"` attribute to the desired elements.

take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1ztswst/)